# PySpark on Databricks getting Relative path in absolute URI: when trying to read in Json Files with DateStamps

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to read in a directory of JSON files to a spark dataframe in databricks and whenever I use the the wildcard character ('*') or when I have multiline enabled I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in 
absolute URI: 2017-08-17T06:01:02Z-077d951a-3848-422b-9a4c-a3b648dde0ac.json'
```

First encountered this when trying to use the the wildcard character:

```
t= 'mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/*.json'
rdf = spark.read.load(t, 'json')
```

and got the above error. Found this strange because when I specified the filepath directly:

```
'dbfs:/mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/2017-08-17T06:01:02Z-077d951a-3848-422b-9a4c-a3b648dde0ac.json'
```

So I implemented this fix:

```
rpaths = list(dbutils.fs.ls("mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/"))
rdf = spark.read.load(rpaths[0].path, 'json')

for i in range(1, len(rpaths)):
  temp = spark.read.load(rpaths[i].path, 'json')
  rdf = rdf.union(temp)
```

Which worked fine until I tried enable multiline json:

```
rpaths = list(dbutils.fs.ls("mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/"))
rdf = spark.read.load(rpaths[0].path, 'json', multiline = 'true')

for i in range(1, len(rpaths)):
  temp = spark.read.load(rpaths[i].path, 'json')
  rdf = rdf.union(temp)
```

and got the same error as above.

Tried to URLEncode because I assumed it had to do with the ':' character in the file name, however it still gives me the same error.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
rpaths = list(dbutils.fs.ls("mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/"))
rdf = spark.read.load(urlparse(rpaths[0].path).path, 'json', multiline = True)
```

Any idea on why this is happening/ how I would fix this?

**EDIT**

Have looked extensively through their documentation and have confirmed that I am providing an absolute path, however it says nothing about ':'s being not supported.

```
t= '/mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/*.json' 
rdf = spark.read.load(t, 'json', multiline = True)
```

Still gives the same issue. The path when using DButils resolves to:

```
 'dbfs:/mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/2017-08-17T06:01:02Z-077d951a-3848-422b-9a4c-a3b648dde0ac.json'
```

Which is an absolute file path

I think it may have to do with the colon (':') character. It seems that ':' has a special meaning in an URI, which is what HDFS uses. I Have tried to escape the character (%3A) but then it says there exists no such path?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Because your filepath doesn't start with a `/` it's relative, but `dbutils` is expecting an absolute filepath. I'm surprised it works at all with the relative filepath...

See their (excellent) docs
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html#access-dbfs-with-dbutils

Comment: Thanks for the response @Steven
I'm not sure that is the issue though:
`t= '/mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/*.json'   rdf = spark.read.load(t, 'json', multiline = True)`
Still gives the same issue.
The path when using DButils resolves to:
`"'dbfs:/mnt/data/2017-08-17/06/2017-08-17T06:01:02Z-077d951a-3848-422b-9a4c-a3b648dde0ac.json'"`
Which is an absolute file path.

Comment: Using their documentation, It seems works for all other files except for the ones with ':'s in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark.read.text reader with whole text , it works also with ":" in file names
, Using from_json we can apply schema to text json.